# How to write a unit test for wasted renders of a react PureComponent or React.memo component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, performance-testing, enzyme, react-testing-library

I created this sandbox to show a situation where a child component wrapped with React.memo can have wasted renders if the parent component is passing down non-primitive props (and not using useCallback or useMemo). There are 2 component rendering the same inner component, one always forces the child to render while the other uses useCallback and doesn't result in wasted renders.

[sandbox example components](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-driscoll-83t6p?file=/src/App.js)

I want to write a unit test with jest and enzyme or jest and react-testing-library to test that the inner component is not re-rendering unnecessarily (to catch and prevent instances where an engineer may add a non-primitive prop to the component and not use useCallback or useMemo).

Comment: this is a very good question. Suppose your component had a callback fn inside render. Whenever it renders it'll call this function. Then you can check if this function has been called twice. just an idea. Of course u can check react memo source code , it has tests there.